# JS filtering an Array item through a value in a nested Array

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out how to properly use .filter() to find an object in an Array by searching for a value in its nested Array.

I have the following data:

```
const orders = [
  {
    id: 1,
    items: [
      {
        itemId: "abc",
      },
      {
        itemId: "def",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    items: [
      {
        itemId: "jkl",
      },
      {
        itemId: "mno",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    items: [
      {
        itemId: "abc",
      },
      {
        itemId: "xyz",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I have the needed `itemId: "abc"` which I need to use to find all the objects that have items that also have the Id of "abc", so that the result is this:

```
 [
  {
    id: 1,
    items: [
      {
        itemId: "abc",
      },
      {
        itemId: "def",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    items: [
      {
        itemId: "abc",
      },
      {
        itemId: "xyz",
      },
    ],
  },
 ]
```

So far, I've tried the following:

```
orders &&
  orders.filter((order) => {
    return order.items.filter((item) => item.itemId === "abc");
  });
```

But it doesn't seem to work. What am I missing here?

Comment: In the inner function you need `oder.items.some` instead. Using filter inside will always result in an array, which will keep all items in the outer filter (since even an empty array is truthy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris G beat me to it in the comments but he is right, you need to use `order.items.some` in your inner function:

```js
const orders = [{
    id: 1,
    items: [{
        itemId: "abc",
      },
      {
        itemId: "def",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    items: [{
        itemId: "jkl",
      },
      {
        itemId: "mno",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    items: [{
        itemId: "abc",
      },
      {
        itemId: "xyz",
      },
    ],
  },
]

var ans = orders.filter((order) => {
  return order.items.some((item) => item.itemId === "abc");
});

console.log(ans)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const orders = [{
    id: 1,
    items: [{
        itemId: "abc",
      },
      {
        itemId: "def",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    items: [{
        itemId: "jkl",
      },
      {
        itemId: "mno",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    items: [{
        itemId: "abc",
      },
      {
        itemId: "xyz",
      },
    ],
  },
];

const result = orders.filter(order =>
  order.items.find(item => item.itemId === 'abc') !== undefined
)

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I chose the answer that included .some after a bit of a research.